# Kotlin MockK: io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for

Tags: kotlin, junit5, mockk, junit-jupiter

This is my code snippet:

```
@Test
fun `request should return anon id if query param present`(@MockK(relaxed = true) req: ServerRequest)
```

I'm using JUnit5(Jupiter).
The exception I've got is:

`io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: ServerRequest(#1).cookies()`

This is weird because if I understood `relaxed` correctly, my instance of ServerRequest should always have some [value](https://mockk.io/#relaxed-mock).

Why doesn't it in my case?

Answer (score 6):

I figured out while I was writing the question that there is another alternative to specify relaxed, via `@RelaxedMockK`. And imagine my surprise, it works:

```
@Test
fun `request should return anon id if query param present`(@RelaxedMockK req: ServerRequest) {
```

Comment: Can you please submit GH issue for it. Both should work